# GoLand package index breaks when using multiple versions of the same module

Tags: go, goland

I need to use both a v1 and alpha version of the `google.golang.org/api/compute` api in a project I'm working on. The need to use the alpha version came up after already using the v1 version for quite a bit of code, and I need to use both versions at once.

When I import the alpha version, GoLand indexing breaks and I lose auto completion and get a bunch of red text/lines in my packages that import alpha. Though, go will still build/run the code just fine.

I've tried clearing my GoLand cache and re-indexing, but am still having the same issue. I've also cleaned my go cache with `go clean -modcache` and `go mod tidy` to download and checksum everything again.

Is there something I'm missing that would make this an issue in GoLand, but my go code still builds and runs fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can navigate to the package sources by pressing `Command/CTRL+Click` on the import statement and find `compute-gen.go` file and size limit warning. The IDE behaves as expected.

[image]

As a workaround, you can invoke `Help | Edit Custome Properties...` and add the following line `idea.max.intellisense.filesize=8500000`, restart GoLand. But please keep in mind that the IDE can be slow when dealing with large files even if they're not open in the editor.

You can read more about the `idea.properties` file [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869).